# Can't "compile" the makefile

Tags: drivers, kernel, makefile

This is the make file:

```
obj-m += hello_pass_arg.o

KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:  
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

When i execute the command "make" i shows the following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.13.14-qd/build SUBDIRS=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.13.14-qd/drivers/hello modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/source/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.13.14-qd/drivers/hello/hello_pass_arg.c', needed by `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.13.14-qd/drivers/hello/hello_pass_arg.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.13.14-qd/drivers/hello] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/source/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I dont understand why does it enter linux-lts-raring-3.8.0!

Comment: What is the location of your `hello_pass_arg.c` file?

Comment: got it! it was somewhere else.. when i moved it to /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.13.14-qd/drivers/hello it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `hello_pass_arg.c` file to a location other than the source code of your linux kernel and it should work.